# Combine spreadsheets in excel according to name

Tags: excel, vba

i need a script to automate combine the multiple excel spreadsheets from same workbook into one spreadsheet according to the name of the spreadsheets. However, the name of the spreadsheets is in different names. for example: 0000a ,0000b,0000c.... How do i compare the first four numbers of the names and if similar, combine them into one spreadsheet with the name 0000? thanks in advance for help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine sheets in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26512995/combine-sheets-in-excel)

Answer (score 1):

Get name with [`Worksheet.Name`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ff196974.aspx), i.e:

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
For Each ws in Worksheets
 MsgBox Left(ws.Name, 4)
Next ws
```

With [`Left`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ie/library/y050k1wb(v=vs.90).aspx) you can extract the first 4 letters. If you store them in an `array` you can use [`Application.Match`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/worksheetfunction-match-method-excel)-Function to match the values in the `array`. With the index you get back you can refer to the `Worksheets(index)`.

EDIT:

```
Sub ad()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lc As Range, lc1 As Range
Dim arr() As String, index As Long, Count As Long

Count = Worksheets.Count
ReDim arr(1 To Count) 'Array to store worksheetsnames

For i = 1 To Count
 arr(i) = Left(Worksheets(i).Name, 4) 'cut 4 letters and store in array
Next

On Error Resume Next

For i = Count To 2 Step -1
 sval = arr(i) 'search value
 ReDim Preserve arr(1 To i - 1) 'downsize array
 index = Application.Match(sval, arr(), 0) 'find matching name in array

    With Worksheets(index) 'lrow on ws to paste
        Set lc = .Cells.Find(what:=Chr(42), after:=.Cells(1), searchdirection:=xlPrevious, _
                         lookat:=xlPart, searchorder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlFormulas)
    End With
    With Worksheets(i) 'lrow on ws to copy
        Set lc1 = .Cells.Find(what:=Chr(42), after:=.Cells(1), searchdirection:=xlPrevious, _
                         lookat:=xlPart, searchorder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlFormulas)
    End With

    Worksheets(i).Range("A1:" & lc1.Address).Copy Worksheets(index).Range("A" & lc.Row + 1) 'copy paste
    Worksheets(index).Name = sval 'rename to first 4 letters
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Worksheets(i).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for ur response, but i am totally fresh to excel vba and this is really hard for me to catch up what u trying to explain. Can u explain it more detail so that i can follow step by step ? thank you so much.

Comment: It is possible to using python scripts to get the same output?

Comment: You can possibly do it with every higher language. I've added an example that work the way ive descriped it.

Comment: It work! thank you so much for this. but some worksheets is duplicated is there any ways to arrange the sheets following the sequences 0000a, 0000b, 0000c and more?

Comment: and after copying the data from the worksheet, i would like to  delete the previous sheet where the data is from. Really thank you so much for help!

Comment: it will delete the old ones now. It only gets duplicated if you run it more than once, when the old ws still exist, that should be fixed now. You can arrange the content when you modify the copy paste statement. atm it will paste the contents below each other.

Comment: i face an error which is For control variable already in use. When i execute this

Comment: Then it interferes with another sub in your code. rename the variable thats already used.

Comment: It did combine the data but it also delete the ws created with combined data. I think i did not explain my question well.

Comment: For example, what i have now is in this format https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/1/d/1h5_FO7MEwqMY8P5qVlTvKbtEiPk6mAUTJYtFVJ4g2jc/pubhtml        and i want it to become  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/1/d/1ZxkA9oQiHc-axoEzYIvVHwbQ5hlhjcHy5qrWoRiNVWc/pubhtml#  this